# MySQL query missing results in node-mysql that are returned in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax, phpmyadmin

My SQL query returns four columns when I run it in phpMyAdmin, but only two when performed through Node.js and the mysql package. I suspect it might have to do with the asynchronicity or with LEFT JOIN, but I can't figure it out.

Node index.js:

```
app.get('/name', function (req,res){
  var query='SELECT s.result, s.distance, hp.result, hp.distance FROM `table15` s LEFT JOIN `table14` hp on s.name = hp.name WHERE s.name = "John Appleseed"';
  pool.query(query,function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```

app.js

```
  $.ajax({
      url : "/name",
      type : "GET",
      success : function(data){
          var len = data.length;
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
```

Returns in browser and console:

```
[{result: "36:24", distance: 12}]
```

But in phpMyAdmin I get four columns and would therefor expect something like this in the browser as well:

```
[{result: "00:35:29", distance: 12, result: "36:24", distance: 12}]
```

Comment: Have you tried altering your query like: `SELECT s.result AS sResult, s.distance AS sDistance, hp.result AS hpResult, hp.distance AS hpDistance FROM table15 s LEFT JOIN table14 hp on s.name = hp.name WHERE s.name = "John Appleseed"` ?

Comment: Which mysql-node version do you use?

Comment: What is the output of the `console.log` on the serverside? Is it the same as the ajax output?

Comment: Filed an issue at GitHub: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1904

Comment: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#joins-with-overlapping-column-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having zero familiarity with `node.js` i would suggest the following. Try altering your query and add names to your result columns.

**Example**

```
SELECT `s`.`result` AS `sResult`, 
`s`.`distance` AS `sDistance`, 
`hp`.`result` AS `hpResult`, 
`hp`.`distance` AS `hpDistance` FROM `table15` `s` 
LEFT JOIN `table14` `hp` on `s`.`name` = `hp`.`name` 
WHERE `s`.`name` = "John Appleseed";
```

The above should output

```
[{sResult: "00:35:29", sDistance: 12, hpResult: "36:24", hpDistance: 12}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix! I think what Mladen suggested is correct, the samen column names were probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is a bug in the library because the output fields are valid and unique, but the library does not handle the literal dot correctly.

You should get `s.result` and `hp.result` but you get variables overwritten without the prefix: `result`.

MySQL solution: Use alias - `SELECT s.result AS sresult, hp.result AS hpresult ...`.

node-mysql solution: Use the [`nestTables` option for overlapping column names](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md#joins-with-overlapping-column-names).

Copied from the linked page:

```
var options = {sql: '...', nestTables: true};
connection.query(options, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  /* results will be an array like this now:
  [{
    table1: {
      fieldA: '...',
      fieldB: '...',
    },
    table2: {
      fieldA: '...',
      fieldB: '...',
    },
  }, ...]
  */
});
```

Or as a string that replaces the literal dot:

```
var options = {sql: '...', nestTables: '_'};
connection.query(options, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  /* results will be an array like this now:
  [{
    table1_fieldA: '...',
    table1_fieldB: '...',
    table2_fieldA: '...',
    table2_fieldB: '...',
  }, ...]
  */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be that your columns are called the same (distance and result) from both tables. 
For JSON to be valid you must not have duplicate keys, names of the columns should be unique.
Try calling them distance1, result1, distance2, result2